# how to replace edited row in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/230/)
There are two rows and each row have 2 bootstrap icons edit and delete.When edit icon is clicked then a bootstrap dialog box appears showing the existing column values,User can change the values and after clicking the save button the old values are replaced by the new one.I tried using

```
$Updaterow.remove();
$Updaterow.append('<td>'+ $('#editName').val()+'/<td>'+'<td>'+ $('#editEmail').val()+'/<td>'+'<td>'+ $('#editmobile').val()+'/<td>');
```

but this is not working.I have also tried with this

```
 $Updaterow.replaceWith('<td>'+ $('#editName').val()+'/<td>'+'<td>'+ $('#editEmail').val()+'/<td>'+'<td>'+ $('#editmobile').val()+'/<td>');
```

In this way also the new row is not getting replaced.Can any body please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to replace TR with a TD. Try this

```
$Updaterow.replaceWith('<tr><td>'+ $('#editName').val()+'</td>'
       +'<td>'+ $('#editEmail').val()+'</td>'
       +'<td>'+ $('#editmobile').val()+'</td></tr>');
```

And the first one wont work since you are appending TD to a TR which is not in DOM any more.

Comment: You have the / before your <td> :) You should have </td> to close it properly.

Comment: @Jake Thx, I've copied this part from the question :)

Comment: @Jake Thanks to you also.i would have upvoted if you also provided a answer.Well your comment also useful

Comment: @YuryTarabanko i am using twitter bootstrap in my app.It works perfectly in browser but When I load it using android emulator then some functions are not working.Do you have any solutions for this?

Comment: @Jake what could be the reason that my app not is opening properly in mobile browser?